# Why is google spreadsheet to JSON url does not work anymore?

Tags: json, android-studio, google-sheets

I am currently working on a dictionary like app in android studio for freshmen in my school's robotics team. I used google spreadsheets as a database and until about a month ago it worked perfectly. one day I open my app and it fails to load the JSON so I try to open it on my web browser and it does not work anymore.

The process to make a JSON url out of a google spreadsheets used to be like this:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/SPREADSHEET-ID/od6/public/basic?alt=json

In my case the complete url is:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1HljdyhGauam-1WYa_C1ho2KOQMUrbGUuR3s5OEU8XtE/od6/public/basic?alt=json

And the url opened a JSON containing all the information in the spreadsheet.

Due to this problem I consider switching to firebase but I am frustrated because it used to work and I do not want to learn an entire new database framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

Comment: I am trying to use an url to access the json of the spreadsheet, I can not find an easy way to do this in the new api without having to create a project in the console cloud and creating credentials and it still does not work.